# Multiple aggregates in SQL starting from a query for a single value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Starting from a *Log* table where are registered differently *Operations* according to a *serial number* for 3 different devices (*ReferenceId*), I'm able to select the desired result for a single *serial number* using the below query:

```
DECLARE @serialNumber varchar(256)
SET @serialNumber = 'XXXXX'

SELECT *
FROM Log
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Log WHERE SerialNumber = @serialNumber AND ReferenceId = 1 ORDER BY Id desc
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Log WHERE SerialNumber = @serialNumber AND ReferenceId = 2 ORDER BY Id desc
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Log WHERE SerialNumber = @serialNumber AND ReferenceId = 3 ORDER BY Id desc
)
AND Operation = 3
```

How can I get the result for all the *serial numbers* using a unique aggregate query?

**UPDATE**

Sample data extracted for a single serial number

```
SELECT Id, SerialNumber, ReferenceId, Operation FROM ActivationLog WHERE SerialNumber = @serialNumber;

6678    XXXXX   1   0
6991    XXXXX   1   1
6992    XXXXX   1   0
7315    XXXXX   1   1
7317    XXXXX   1   0
7396    XXXXX   1   1
7397    XXXXX   1   0
7581    XXXXX   3   3
7582    XXXXX   3   1
7587    XXXXX   3   3
7588    XXXXX   3   1
7595    XXXXX   1   0
7596    XXXXX   1   1
7597    XXXXX   1   0
7598    XXXXX   1   1
7599    XXXXX   1   0
7632    XXXXX   1   1
7633    XXXXX   1   0
7758    XXXXX   1   1
7784    XXXXX   1   0
7898    XXXXX   1   1
7899    XXXXX   1   0
```

Using my query result is 0 rows.
Trying the query suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen (but filtered for the single serial number), I get 1 row.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Id, SerialNumber, ReferenceId, Operation
FROM ActivationLog
WHERE ReferenceId IN (1, 2, 3) AND Operation = 3 AND SerialNumber=@serialNumber
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY Id DESC)

7587    XXXXX   3   3
```

Comment: Please show sample data (as DDL+DML) and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: I highly recommend using `UNION ALL` over `UNION` unless you specifically want to remove duplicates and suffer the performance penalty that goes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated question, it seems you want something along these lines:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber, ReferenceId
                                 ORDER BY Id DESC) rn
    FROM Log
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND ReferenceId IN (1, 2, 3) AND Operation = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the quick reply. I tried both of your hints but I don't get exactly the same results. For example, there is a serial number where I get 0 results using my single query and 1 row using yours. Problem is that your query seems not to consider only the first row ordered by Id. Let me know if you need a concrete sample to better understand, thanks.

Comment: I won't speculate what might be wrong with my answer (or your question) without first seeing some sample data.  Add sample data to your question which clearly explains the logic you want.

Comment: @ilCosmico Check the updated answer which I think might be what you want.  Now I am partitioning on serial number and reference ID, then restricting to only a handful of reference IDs in the outer query.

Comment: I just checked it, but the result for serial XXXXX still gives the row with Id 7587

Comment: Try moving the restriction on `Operation` to the outer query.

Comment: It did the trick! Thanks a lot for your effort, please update your answer so I can flag it as the correct one :)